# How to join strcpy in C++

Tags: c++, join, strcpy

im confused, in my coding C++
please help me..

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream.h>
main()
{
    char h1[80];
    char h2[80];
    char move[80];
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Character 1 = ";
    gets(h1);
    cout<<"Character 2 = ";
    gets(h2);
    strcpy(move, h1);
    cout<<"Result = "<<move;
    getch();
}
```

I want output/result program like

```
Move  =  h1+h2;
```

Comment: Use `std::string` for `h1` and `move`, then `move = h1 + h2;`.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Please don't say it's the ancient Turbo C++.

Comment: Never ever ever use `gets()`.  It is a security hole.  Use `fgets()` or something else.

Comment: Why are you mixing C and C++?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think it matters once you see `#include <iostream.h>` in the preprocessor list. That's just plain *ugh*. (uptick, btw).

Comment: I think you need `std::strcpy()` followed by `std::strcat()`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck if you use C11-compliant libc, `gets()` doesn't even exist.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It seems to me that as long as he is using `cout` he should use `cin`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You know of anything else that tolerates the implicit `int` on `main`? But Turbo C++ or not, any compiler which accepts this code belongs in a previous century.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
main()
{
    std::string h1;
    std::string h2;
    std::string move;
    std::cout << "Character 1 = ";
    std::cin >> h1;
    std::cout << "Character 2 = ";
    std::cin >> h2;
    move = h1 +h2;
    std::cout << "Result = " << move;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use strcat to concatenate strings

```
strcpy(move, h1);
strcat(move, h2);
cout<<"Result = "<<move;
```

Comment: I'd point out that this could cause UB since `h1`, `h2`, and `move` are all of the same size, so if eg `h1` had a length of 30 and `h2` had a length of 30 we would be writing outside `move`, but the OP is using `gets` so buffer overflow seems not to be of concern.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

main()
{
    std::string h1;
    std::string h2;
    std::string move;
    clrscr();
    std::cout << "Character 1 = ";
    std::getline(std::cin, h1);
    std::cout << "Character 2 = ";
    std::getline(std::cin, h2);
    move = h1 + h2;
    std::cout << "Result = " << move;
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `strcat(move,h2);` to add content of `move` and `h2` variable

```
strcpy(move, h1);
strcat(move,h2);   // make sure `move` have enough space to concatenate  `h1` and `h2`
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be better to use C function `fgets` instead of `C function gets` because the last is unsafe and can overwrite memory..

For example

```
fgets( h1, 80, stdin );
```

But in any case it would be even  better to use standard C++ function `getline`.

If you want to get the result as Move = h1+h2 then you should check that Move can accomodate the string concatenation `h1 + h2`

So you could write

```
if ( strlen( h1 ) + strlen( h2 ) < 80 )
{
    strcat( strcpy( move, h1 ), h2 );
    cout<<"Result = "<<move;
}
```

Comment: The question is C++ - This is s C answer

Comment: @Ed Heal It is the most useful answer relative to his code.

Comment: @EdHeal The code was C apart from the use of cout (without even a std:: in it)

Comment: @TomTanner - It is tagged as C++ and I took that as the author wants C++ code

Comment: @Ed Heal He does not want  neither C nor C++ code. He wants  that he could use C string functios with character arrays. And my answer is the most useful for him. He needs not at this stage to know about for example std::string because he did not even learn about then yet.